# Twitter Bootstrap Collapse not collapsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the bootstrap collapse navbar, I can expanded but I can't collapse the navigation.

And I can't find anything wrong with it:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse nav-justified">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="http://revad.dev/news/">News</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="menu-menu" class=" nav navbar-nav">
                <li id="menu-item-5" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-5"><a href="http://revad.dev/">Accueil</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-290" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-290"><a href="http://revad.dev/#le-projet">Le Projet</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-291" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-291"><a href="http://revad.dev/#partenaires">Partenaires</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-292" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-292"><a href="http://revad.dev/#lavenir-du-projet">L&rsquo;avenir</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-293" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-293"><a href="http://revad.dev/#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: How are you trying to collapse it? By clicking away?

Comment: yep, no javascript at all

Comment: I assume you have included the bootstrap JavaScript?

Comment: and bootstrap CSS wich handles mediaqueries ...

Comment: @Danko, I experience OPs issue on your jsfiddle.

Comment: i cant see it fom work something's blocking jsfiddle

Comment: wich version of bootstrap?

Comment: Bootstrap.js v2.1.2 by fat & mdo - Hold on that seems wrong...

Comment: What a moron! I'm using Version 3 CSS but version 2 javascript... Can't work... I've updated the JS files and now works just fine. Thanks guys. @Danko write an answer and ill validate

Comment: XD lol ... no problem you can post your own answer you find it :)

Answer (score 1):

Was just using Bootstrap v3 CSS but v2 JS.

Updated javascript files to v3 and it worked all fine.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have a few classes called `current_*`. If you have multiple active classes the collapse function would not work since it needs one or a sub set of items to activate and deactivate.
Making sure that `items` are only active when they should be will ensure that bootstrap's jquery can select and hide the appropriate `items`.